# FIND formula using structured references in Tables gives #VALUE Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using a value in one table as a search criterion, looking to work with all rows with a match in one column of another table. My current formula gives `#VALUE!` error at this point:

```
{=FIND([@Col1],Table2[Col3])}
```

[EDIT]:

My actual formula is more like:

```
{=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND([@Col1],Table2[Col3]))),DO WORK ON THOSE ROWS,0)}
```

Sample image: 
[image: Example Tables]

[/Edit]

This gives me a `#VALUE!` error for every entry in `Table2[Col3]` unless the search criterion appears in the first cell in `Table2[Col3]`, then I get correctly returned position 1 (it's always going to be at the start of the cell).

I need the formula to check all cells in `Table2[Col3]` (rather than the above formula which only checks the first cell) for the resulting position of my criterion, then continue working with that array as part of a lengthy `SUMPRODUCT`.

Can anyone spot my obvious (or not so obvious, hopefully) mistake?

Comment: Just to be clear, can you show us some sample data and desired output.

Comment: And is this formula going in a cell by itself?

Comment: Thank you guys, added more details between Edit 'tags' (not-tags, actually, but hopefully it's clear above). I have since tried using SUMPRODUCT without the preceding IF statement I'm querying here, which is basically checking if there are any matches at all before proceeding with the SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IFERROR(MATCH([@col1],Table2[col3],0),"")`

Should have the desired effect. If you are looking for a Boolean, just use

`IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH([@col1],Table2[col3],0)),"True","False")`

**EDIT:**

If you are looking for the information anywhere in the cell, make use of the wildcards, most common ones are `*` for any number of any character and `?` for any *SINGLE* character:

`=IFERROR(MATCH("*"&[@col1]&"*",Table2[col3],0),"")`

or for your use:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&[@col1]&"*",Table2[col3],0)),{DO WORK ON THOSE ROWS},0)`

[image]

Comment: Ah, apologies. I simplified my sample data too far! The real data has "Yesxyz" in its Col3 cells. Hence the need for Find. I'm so sorry. Yes and No are good examples because the length of the real data is never the same either.

Comment: @user3576175 Okay, so you are looking for the "Yes" part and ignoring the gibberish afterwards then? I guess you don't care about the relative position as you are using find?

Comment: Perfect, I completely forgot about wildcards. Thank you for the syntax with structured references as well, that is something I would have struggled to find.

Comment: @user3576175 glad to be of assistance